# bulk insert for elasticsearch nest 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, version, nest, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I have been trying to use to the bulk insert function but every time I use it is showing some mapping error . Has the bulk insert function declaration have changed from nest 1.x to nest 5.x because in 5.x nest documentation I did not find the .bulk() function . Please Suggest

Code for bulk insert:

```
        public void bulkInsert(List<BaseData> recordList, List<String> listOfIndexName)
    {

          BulkDescriptor descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
            descriptor.Index<BaseData>(op => op
                .Document(recordList[j])
                .Index(listOfIndexName[j])

               );


        }

        var result = clientConnection.Bulk(descriptor);


    }
```

My list of data that I am passing looks something like this :

```
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "number")]


class TicketData : BaseData
{        
    //[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = true)]


    [Date(Name = "sys_updated_on", Store = true)]
    public DateTimeOffset sys_updated_on { get; set; }


      [Text(Name = "number", Store = true)] 
    public override string  number { get; set; }


   [Text(Name = "incident_state", Store = true)]
    public string incident_state { get; set; }


  [Text(Name = "location", Store = true)]
    public string location { get; set; }


   [Text(Name = "assigned_to", Store = true)]
    public string assigned_to { get; set; }



[Text(Name = "u_knowledge_id", Store = true)]
    public string u_knowledge_id { get; set; }


    [Text(Name = "u_knowledge_id.u_process_role", Store = true)]
    public string u_knowledge_id_u_process_role { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: This solution might help you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017858/how-to-bulk-insert-json-using-nest-elasticsearch

Or you can refer to this, from this link you can get more basic idea about bulk insert thank you!

Comment: you look like you're missing code in your example e.g. what is `descriptor`? could you edit your question to add that detail please. Also, what is the mapping error? what error does Elasticsearch return? what does the bulk request json look like?

Comment: I have added the descriptor Russ. Still the error is the same

Comment: The error is something like this  [0] {index returned 400 _index: datd.ticketlog01-2017.15 _type: basedata _id: IN1 _version: 0 error: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Can't merge a non object mapping [u_knowledge_id] with an object mapping [u_knowledge_id]" CausedBy: ""} Nest.BulkResponseItemBase {Nest.BulkIndexResponseItem}

Answer (score 2):

It seems that NEST cannot infer the correct type of your entity because you specify generic type `BaseData` whereas the actual type is `TicketData`. You should specify the actual type of entity you want to index. Since you may have different types inside your list, you can get the actual type using `GetType()` method:

```
descriptor.Index<BaseData>(op => op
    .Document(recordList[j])
    .Index(listOfIndexName[j])
    .Type(recordList[j].GetType())
);
```

Currently your query tries to dynamically create a different type with default mapping instead of interpreting it as existing type with explicit mapping

Comment: The error isDebugInformation  `"Invalid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /_bulk\r\n# Invalid Bulk items:\r\n  operation[0]: index returned 400 _index: datd.ticketlog01-2017.15 _type: ticketdata _id: IN1 _version: 0 error: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: \"Can't merge a non object mapping [u_knowledge_id] with an object mapping [u_knowledge_id]\" CausedBy: \"\"\r\n  operation[1]: index returned 400 _index: datd.ticketlog01-2016.30 _type: ticketdata`

Comment: Looks like a field type conflict with other object type. What other mappings do you have?